# Reference request:  Forcing Axiom for the class of Axiom A posets

Tags: set-theory, reference-request, lo.logic

Does anyone know of a paper which asks, or conjectures about, the following question?

QUESTION:  Is the Forcing Axiom for Axiom A posets equiconsistent with the Proper Forcing Axiom (PFA)?

Axiom A posets are a subclass of the proper posets, defined by Baumgartner around the same time as the discovery of proper forcing by Shelah.  Many consequences of PFA (e.g. those involving finite iterations of c.c.c. and $\sigma$-closed posets) are consequences of the Forcing Axiom for Axiom A.

Comment: Sean, are you aware that Ishiu showed that $\lt\omega_1$-properness is equivalent to being forcing-equivalent to an Axiom A forcing?

Comment: Hi Stefan.  I'm aware of the result, but I cannot access the paper (even through the university).  

Comment: I am not aware of any papers directly asking for this equiconsistency, rather than via large cardinals (asking or conjecturing that both are equiconsistent with a supercompact). But you are interested in a paper directly asking about the two forcing axioms, right? Not via a large cardinal intermediary.

Comment: (By the way, Ishiu's paper does not ask any questions on equiconsistency. I can email you the paper if you need it.)

Comment: @Andres:  yes, I'm interested in a paper directly asking about the forcing axioms, not via a large cardinal intermediary.  I'd appreciate it if you emailed the paper.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andres:  I mean the paper of Ishiu, even though it doesn't ask any such questions.

Comment:  I almost asked about the consistency strength of Axiom A on here last year, but I got distracted!

Comment: My argument was not correct.  Menachem Magidor found an error and a counterexample to the way I stated the theorem.      

Answer (score 2):

this may help (building on earlier work by [Ishiu](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/fm/Inf/186-1-2.html) and [Weinert](http://elbe.math.uni-bonn.de/people/weinert/BAAFA.pdf)):

[Bounded forcing axioms and Baumgartner's conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2275), by Aspero, Friedman, Mota & Sabok.

> We study the spectrum of forcing
>   notions between the iterations of
>   σ-closed followed by ccc forcings and
>   the proper forcings. This includes the
>   hierarchy of α-proper forcings for
>   indecomposable countable ordinals α as
>   well as the Axiom A forcings. We focus
>   on the bounded forcing axioms for the
>   hierarchy of α-proper forcings and
>   connect them to a hierarchy of weak
>   club guessing principles. We show that
>   they are, in a sense, dual to each
>   other. In particular, these weak club
>   guessing principles separate the
>   bounded forcing axioms for distinct
>   countable indecomposable ordinals. In
>   the study of forcings completely
>   embeddable into an iteration of
>   σ-closed followed by ccc forcing, we
>   present an equivalent characterization
>   of this class in terms of
>   Baumgartner’s Axiom A. This resolves a
>   well-known conjecture of Baumgartner
>   from the 1980’s.

Comment: I am familiar with this paper, and it does not address Sean's question in any way.